# How to make header of selected pivot bold in a Pivot in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp

I have a pivot with a header template, in this pivot.
The condition here is I would like to make the textblock bold only if the pivot is selected.
I tried editing the Pivot style but no as I couldn't find what to change there.

```
<Pivot x:Name="mainContentPivot"  Grid.Row="1"
       ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CategoriesPivotItemsStyle}"
       >
    <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TitleHeaders}" FontSize="16" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
</Pivot>
```

Any clues as to how to achieve this,
Thanks.

Comment: You'll just need to edit the [style template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299142.aspx) and add a storyboard to the `Selected` state in the VisualStateManager to alter the FontWeight of ContentPresenter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1. Get the `PivotHeaderItem` template from *%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10240.0\Generic\generic.xaml*
2. Use it to style your `PivotHeaderItem`
3. Edit the `Selected` VisualState to add this `Setter`:

   `<Setter Target="ContentPresenter.FontWeight" Value="Bold" />`

Get back to me if you need any help.

The code is here for you:

```
<Pivot>
...
...
    <Pivot.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemThemeFontWeight}" />
            <Setter Property="CharacterSpacing" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemMargin}" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="48" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
                        <Grid
                        x:Name="Grid"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Grid.Resources>
                                    <Style x:Key="BaseContentPresenterStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="XamlAutoFontFamily"/>
                                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold" />
                                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                                        <Setter Property="LineStackingStrategy" Value="MaxHeight"/>
                                        <Setter Property="TextLineBounds" Value="Full"/>
                                        <Setter Property="OpticalMarginAlignment" Value="TrimSideBearings"/>
                                    </Style>
                                    <Style x:Key="BodyContentPresenterStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseContentPresenterStyle}">
                                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" />
                                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemThemeFontWeight}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontSize}"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </Grid.Resources>
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                            <VisualTransition From="Unselected" To="UnselectedLocked" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" />
                                            <VisualTransition From="UnselectedLocked" To="Unselected" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" />
                                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" >
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                        <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedLocked">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                                     Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemLockedTranslation}" />
                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                                     Duration="0" To="0" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" >
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" >
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
    <!-- Here is where it goes -->          <VisualState.Setters>
                                                <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                            </VisualState.Setters>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPointerOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" >
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" >
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" >
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" >
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPressed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" >
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" >
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" >
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" >
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <ContentPresenter
                        x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                        FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                        FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                    <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" />
                                    </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Pivot.Resources>
    </Pivot>
```

Comment: Seriously ? I need to do all of this just to make it bold ?